# Scale down a array contained in an equation - beamer

Tags: beamer, equations, scaling, arrays

I have an array inside an equation in a beamer presentation. I tried scaling it down using `resizebox` but it gives me error :

```
\begin{equation}
\label{eq:recursive}
\resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{
R_{k+1}(a,b) =
\left\{ \begin{array}{rl}
1 & \mbox{if } a=b \\
0 &  \mbox{if } I(a)=\phi \mbox{ or } I(b)=\phi \\
\frac{C}{|I(a)||I(b)|}\sum_{i=1}^{|I(a)|}\sum_{j=1}^{|I(b)|} R_k(I_i(a),I_j(b)) & \mbox{otherwise } \\
\end{array}\right.
}
\end{equation}
```

any suggestions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you really need numbering, you can do like

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Big formula}

\begin{equation}
\label{eq:recursive}
\resizebox{.9\textwidth}{!}{$\displaystyle % restart math mode!
R_{k+1}(a,b) =
\begin{dcases}
1 & \text{if $a=b$} \\
0 & \text{if $I(a)=\phi$ or $I(b)=\phi$} \\
\frac{C}{|I(a)|\,|I(b)|}
  \sum_{i=1}^{|I(a)|}
  \sum_{j=1}^{|I(b)|} R_k(I_i(a),I_j(b)) & \text{otherwise}
\end{dcases}
$} % end math mode and close the box to be resized
\end{equation}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Note that I used `dcases` provided by `mathtools`, which gains some horizontal space as the limits are typeset above and below the summation sign. Alternatively, you can type

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Big formula}

\begin{equation}
\label{eq:recursive}
\resizebox{.9\textwidth}{!}{$\displaystyle % restart math mode
R_{k+1}(a,b) =
\begin{cases}
1 & \text{if $a=b$} \\
0 & \text{if $I(a)=\phi$ or $I(b)=\phi$} \\
\frac{C}{|I(a)|\,|I(b)|}
  \sum\limits_{i=1}^{|I(a)|}
  \sum\limits_{j=1}^{|I(b)|} R_k(I_i(a),I_j(b)) & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$} % end math mode and close the box to be resized
\end{equation}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

This will use smaller summation signs.

[image]

***Notes.***

1. The `cases` (or `dcases`) environment is more convenient than using `array`.
2. For the conditions, it's better to use `\text` and switch to math mode inside it, rather than using clumsy `\mbox` commands with spaces.

Comment: or `cases*` or `dcases` which typeset the second column in text mode, so no `\text` needed.

Answer (score 2):

You are not in math mode inside the argument of the `\resizebox` command. You can get back into (display) math mode using dollar signs and `\displaystyle`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\label{eq:recursive} 
\resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{$\displaystyle a = b$}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Note that the `equation` environment is partly redundant here; it can be omitted in cases where you don't need numbering.